# How to use the flutter native splash screen

Tags: flutter

I am facing trouble using the flutter native splash screen.A blank screen appears when i tried to use the flutter_native_splash package https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_native_splash

Comment: What platform are you having trouble with?  Can you post your `flutter_native_splash` config from `pubspec.yaml`?  Have you run the command `flutter pub run flutter_native_splash:create`?

Comment: I am using android platform

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The actual and perfect way is not to add a page or use a plugin, you can even do it natively by this method:
Go to => andoid > app > main > res > drawable > in this folder you can see a file called lauch_background open it,

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <!-- Modify this file to customize your launch splash screen -->
 <layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item android:drawable="@android:color/white" />

  <!-- You can insert your own image assets here -->
   <item>
    <bitmap
        android:gravity="fill"
        android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher" />
  </item>
   </layer-list>
```

add your image in the folder and rename the image file name to ic_launcher. Also uncomment the commented code in the file.

Answer (score 10):

You can create native splash screen for both (android, iOS) platform to follow the doc (manually) (https://docs.flutter.dev/development/ui/advanced/splash-screen) but I will recommend you to use `flutter_native_splash` plugin cause it will save your time and create less opportunity of mistakes.

Create a new assets and logos folder in your root project path and place your `splash_screen_logo.png` like this `[project_name]/assets/logos/splash_screen_logo.png`

Add `flutter_native_splash: ^2.2.16` at `dev_dependencies` in `pubspec.yaml` (please replace `^2.2.16 version` with the latest version number. [Check it](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_native_splash))

```
dev_dependencies:
  flutter_test:
    sdk: flutter

  flutter_native_splash: ^2.2.16
```

Paste this below code in your `pubspec.yaml` and change the color and image asset path

```
flutter_native_splash:
  color: "#071b5d"
  image: assets/logos/splash_screen_logo.png
  android: true
  ios: true
```

Finally in your project path terminal, run this command: `flutter pub run flutter_native_splash:create` and it will generate native splash screen for both android and iOS.

Answer (score 1):

Two Packages are Needed If you want to Add a Native Flutter Splash screen and Change App Icon using Easy Method

1. flutter_native_splash 2.2.16
2. flutter_launcher_icons

[Flutter native splash screen and App icon change - Easy Method](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=11P_3ZNh-4s)

Answer (score 1):

In `pubspec.yaml`:

```
dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter
  flutter_native_splash: ^2.2.19

flutter_native_splash:
  android: true
  ios: true
  web: false
  color: "#024959"
  image: "img/SplashScreen.png"
```

then, in the terminal:

```
flutter clean
flutter pub get
flutter pub run flutter_native_splash:create
```

Answer (score 0):

refer this example for you native splash screen
https://www.codegrepper.com/code-examples/whatever/flutter+native+splash+screen

Answer (score 0):

this is the right code, the right indentation matters

```
 flutter_native_splash: ^2.2.16
```

flutter_native_splash:
color: "#004ab9"
images: assets/finviobackground.png
android: true
ios: true

Comment: run flutter clean
run flutter pub get
run flutter pub run flutter_native_splash:createboom you will get this message once its successful 
✅ Native splash complete.
Now go finish building something awesome!  You rock! 
Like the package? Please give it a  here: https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_native_splash

Answer (score 0):

In order to use native splash in both ios and android, it will be a daunty task to go the manual way. So in  my opinion, just stick with flutter_native_splash package.

first of all, install the package

```
flutter_native_splash: ^2.3.2
```

then add the following to your pubspec.yaml, following the right indentation;

```
flutter_native_splash:
        color: "#007AFF"
        image: assets/images/app-logo.png
        android: true
        ios: true

flutter:

  uses-material-design: true

  assets:
    - assets/images/
    - assets/svg/
```

Then run the following command in the terminal

```
dart run flutter_native_splash:create
```

This will automatically create your native splash screen for both ios and android without the need for doing it manually.

Answer (score 0):

You can add the native splash screen in both android & iOS by reading the flutter native splash package description catefully.

https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_native_splash

Step 1 : First, add `flutter_native_splash` as a dependency in your `pubspec.yaml` file.

```
dependencies:
  flutter_native_splash: ^2.3.3
```

Step 2 : The you add the code Setting the splash screen via add this section to `pubspec.yaml` file.

```
flutter_native_splash:
  color: "#ffffff"
  image: assets/splash.png
  branding: assets/splash.png
  color_dark: "#ffffff"
  image_dark: assets/splash.png
  branding_dark: assets/splash.png

  android_12:
    image: assets/splash.png
    icon_background_color: "#ffffff"
    image_dark: assets/splash.png
    icon_background_color_dark: "#ffffff"

flutter:
  uses-material-design: true
  assets:
    - assets/
```

Step 3 : After adding your settings, run the following command in the terminal.

```
dart run flutter_native_splash:create
```

Step 4 : If still Not appear the proper splash screen then you can add the set up app initialisation.

```
import 'package:flutter_native_splash/flutter_native_splash.dart';
    
    void main() {
      WidgetsBinding widgetsBinding = WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
      FlutterNativeSplash.preserve(widgetsBinding: widgetsBinding);
      runApp(const MyApp());
    }
    
    // whenever your initialization is completed, remove the splash screen:
        FlutterNativeSplash.remove();
```

This Solution might be work for you..